# Build multiple docker image from single docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In a Micro-service pattern, I have three node application
Application A
Application B
Application C

The process of building docker image for these micro service is same, right now, node modules are installed three times, how can I avoid this duplicate node modules.

I would like to avoid node install 3 times, rather do it once and copy them to different images.

Comment: multi-stage builds or build chains (use previous image as source of current build)

Comment: You can make a Node image with the stuff you need and use that as the base image for your microservices.

Answer (score 0):

For better answer will would be know your Dockerfile.
For this issue You can use a different entrypoint. For Application A entrypoint_a.sh, for Application B entrypoint_b.sh an Application C entrypoint_c.sh

You must copy this 3 files when docker build, into Dockerfile :

```
---
COPY /path/entrypoint_*.sh /image/path
---
```

And the command to run docker image will be :

```
docker run -d --name application_A -p your_port:docker_port --entrypoint /image/path/entrypoint_a.sh  your_builded_immage:tag
```

Next step will be same with --name application_B and C and with entrypoint entrypoint_b.sh and entrypoint_c.sh

Comment: ***FROM node:12-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 4444

# Running default command 
CMD ["node", "main"]

COPY package.json ./

COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --production

COPY ./dist/apps/servers/mulesoft-connector ./***

Comment: same file but with different port and different copy (files)